# Git config still contains extraheader keys. It may cause errors

Tags: git, azure-yaml-pipelines

> Git config still contains extraheader keys. It may cause errors.  To remove the credential, execute `git config --unset-all key-name` from the repository root.

This warning keeps popping up on my pipeline runs(does nothing but its annoying to see it out there). There is a place in codebase where we do an unset of credential and then add in the credentials. This is occurring only on the self hosted agents(mac). How do I get rid of these warnings?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/3807